# Why new background is not being rendered in styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to retrieve image url from API and use it as a background, for that I need to use styled-components. 
This is my app code:

```
const API_KEY = `some key`;

class App extends React.Component{

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            background: ""
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const todayDate = new Date();

        this.getImage(todayDate);
      }

    getImage = async (date) => {
        console.log('connecting...');
        const URL = `https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${API_KEY}`;
        const apiCall = await fetch(URL);

        const data = await apiCall.json();
        this.setState({
            background: data.url
        });
        console.log(data);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <MainContainer>
                <Header>Picture</Header>
                <Image background={this.state.background}/>
            </MainContainer>
        )
    }
}
```

code from `Image`:

```
const ImageDiv = styled.img`
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background: url(${props => props.background});
`;

class Image extends React.Component{
    render(){
        console.log("+++"+this.props.background)
        const url = this.props.background;
        return(
            <ImageDiv src={url}></ImageDiv>
        )
    }
}

export default Image;
```

I tried using `this.props.background`, but it didn't work as well. I always get my element with `background: url();`. Where did I go wrong? I want to send as a props new background url that I get from API and set it as styled-components `background`. For comparison, I set background as image src on element and it works, but I need url to work in styling.

My console output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the background as the `src` prop to `ImageDiv`, but using `props.background`. Try:

```
const ImageDiv = styled.div`
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background: url(${props => props.src});
`;
```